# How do I troubleshoot an electric furnace?

Tags: repair, furnace

I have a Coleman 3300-9051 electric furnace w/AC. The blower continually runs.

Where do I find a repair manual and/or what could be the problem.
How do I test it.

Comment: Are you sure you got the model number right? I was able to find [this site](http://search.mobilehomepartsstore.com/owners-manual-coleman-electric-furnace). If you select one of the furnaces here, and click `Technical Specifications` on the page it leads you to it will open a PDF with quite a bit of information.

Comment: Yes I am sure of the model number, but its a relic like 1985 so its fairly old

Comment: I was also told it may be a sequencer problem

Comment: Found out the heat pump has blown the fuses the circuit breaker was tripped. When I reset it, it blew the fuses. MAJOR ISSUES NOW.

Comment: fuses/circuit breaker, electric furnace/heat pump, lot of conflicting descriptions. It's not really clear what's happening.

Comment: the outside disconnect fuses were blown. the panel circuit breaker was tripped. had it checked by an HVAC tech and the compressor is shorted. NEW FURNACE AND HEATPUMP installed last week

Answer (score 1):

Couple possibilities I can think of:

- Thermal switch in the furnace is broken, making it appear to be too hot, and the blower is running to cool it off.
- Thermostat has the fan switch set to "on" instead of "auto"

Check the thermostat before trying to work on the furnace itself.

Comment: I have checked the thermostat and it is set to auto. The t-stat was replaced last year with a digital readout model

Comment: Possible but incorrect

Comment: @bluexrider Note that the thermal switch that would run the blower isn't in the thermostat, it's part of the furnace.

Comment: I found a circuit breaker thrown in the panel. I reset it and the two 30 amp fuses in-line with the heat-pump blew out. I replaced them and reset the circuit breaker again and the same thing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Probably just a stuck relay.  Happened to me on my HVAC blower motor this Summer.

There will most likely be a main control board for the furnace and the relay is probably there. As far as testing, you'd have to remove it and supply the voltage that the furnace does, to the right pins, while testing the other pins for continuity/disconnect. You'd need info specific to your furnace/relay to do that (as well as knowing and following the appropriate electrical safety rules) I wouldn't just replace it without testing as they can cost $35+.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to test and resolve this?

Comment: Where would this item be and should I replace it as good measure?

Comment: There will most likely be a main control board for the furnace and the relay is probably there.  As far as testing, you'd have to remove it and supply the voltage that the furnace does, to the right pins, while testing the other pins for continuity/disconnect.  You'd need info specific to your furnace/relay to do that (as well as knowing and following the appropriate electrical safety rules)  I wouldn't just replace it without testing as they can cost $35+.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch I added your comment into the answer, could you please delete the comment.  For future reference, if you want to add information to an answer/question they are always editable (just click `edit` at the bottom of the answer/question, add the info, and click `save edits`).